# When I upload image in node, it throws ENOENT error

Tags: node.js, enoent

When I upload image in node , it throws ENOENT error:

```
Error: spawn identify ENOENT
        at _errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
        at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:190:19)
        at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:372:16)
        at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
        at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:218:9)
      code: 'ENOENT',
      errno: 'ENOENT',
      syscall: 'spawn identify',
      path: 'identify',
      spawnargs: [ '-verbose', '-' ] }
```

Comment: show your code?